# Codeigniter INSERT Query for SQL Server Multi language with prefix N not working

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter-3

In Codeigniter following work if I pass static string or write a raw query.

```
$data = array('lang' => 'N'.'مرحبا بالعالم'  );

$this->db->insert('tbl_name', $data);
```

and

```
$lang = $this->input->post('lang', true);

$query = $this->db->query("UPDATE tbl_name SET Name = N'".$lang."'
WHERE tbl_name.id= '".$id."'");
```

However when I try this with post values its now working

```
$ins['lang'] = "N'".$this->input->post('lang', true);

//OR $ins['lang'] = "N'".$this->input->post('lang', true)."'";

$this->db->insert($tableName, $ins);
```

Comment: FYI, SQL Server 2008 ran *completely* out of support almost *4 years ago*.It is long past time you implemented your finalise upgrade path at this time.

Comment: are your post values in "unicode"?

Comment: This very question proves Unicode just works - StackOverflow uses SQL Server to store Unicode strings. The problem is the code that uses string concatenation to construct a SQL query instead of using parameters. In a parameterized query there's no need for the `N` prefix or even quotes. The parameter values are passed outside the query itself to the server, as part of the RPC call

Comment: Creating SQL queries by concatenating input like this exposes you to both conversion errors and SQL injection attacks. Imagine what would happen if `lang` contained `'; DROP TABLE STUDENT;--`. Or `banana'; --`